# Refer to state in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have set the state in a component as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        minutes: 3,
        interests: {
          business: false,
          code: false,
          design: false
        }
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="content">
          <div className="centered-wrapper">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
              <Route path="/life" component={Life} />
              <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
              <Route path="*" component={Welcome}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>                
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And I'm trying to use the state in one of the components managed by the router in the following way:

```
export class Welcome extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errors: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="Welcome">
               <input className="minutes" type="number" defaultValue={ this.state.minutes } /> minutes. 
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is state not global by default?

Comment: State is only available inside the component which defines it. If you want to use state in another component, you have to pass it using props.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can I pass props via the Route?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer with some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is only available inside the component which defines it. If you want to use state in another component, you have to pass it using props.

To pass props along with your `Route`, you can use the [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) function.

You can then call your component using:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Welcome {...props} minutes={this.state.minutes} />} />
```

And then in the `Welcome` components use the passed `minutes` prop instead of state.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add `{...props}` if all I need is the state?

Comment: also: how can I pass a function this way?

Comment: Functions can be called by `<Welcome myFunc={() => {console.log("Hello");}} />`. `{...props}` passes on the default route props that would be passed when using `<Route path="..." component={Welcome} />`